# How to position a div fixed on the bottom of the page in mobile view?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I am working on a website and I am a beginner.
I have a div with div id #dvid that I have made to act as a button. I want it to be on the bottom part of the page when viewed on mobile however, no matter how I try to set its position bottom to 0, it only stays on top.

here is the website I am working on: https://tryslimleaf.com/d24/indexwritten.php#a2c

I want it to stay on the bottom of the page fixed.

another problem on mobile view is when I tap on the said button, it turns into orange. I don't know why. I want it to stay the same color when tapped.

Edit:The text inside the button is "Ready to order" it is on top right side if viewed on mobile.

Sorry for my bad English it is not my primary language. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your button becomes orange because of this `#dvid:hover {
    background-color: #FF8B19;
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect css there is

[image]

that `top: 1%` is the main reason why your button always stays in top. So you need put `top: auto` on your media query. Here is the example from your site:

[image]

Then result is:

[image]

Hope you it helps your problem. If you want that button always on bottom then just remove that `top: 1%` then add `bottom: 1%` or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try to remove top: 1% and also I did try to make it top: auto. the button is not on the bottom for mobile but now the button no longer shows on desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

On that website, you have a `top: 1%` setting for that button. Just change that to `bottom: 1%`

Comment: if he wants to keep it on top when not on mobile, then its better to set `top:unset` in the media query.

Comment: hey, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, if I remove or change the value of top: 1% to either top: auto, top: unset or remove it entirely, the button will no longer show on the desktop. it will only show on mobile at the bottom.